# How to make prop on img component !important?

Tags: css, reactjs

I created a logo component to display my logo in various parts of my site. I am having an issue where a prop (width) is being overruled and my image is stretched horizontally. I know I could deal with it in the styling for the page it is occurring on... But is there a way to deal with this issue within the component itself?

```
import logo from '../../MY_icon_black.png'
import React from 'react'

const Component = () =>
  <div className="MYLogo MYLogoMark">
    <img src={logo} alt="logo" height="90" width="90" />
  </div>

export default Component
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add inline style to your component, `!important` should work here :

```
<img src={logo} alt="logo" height="90" width="90" style={{ width: '90px' }} />
```